# How to use SELECT... FOR UPDATE for record which doesn't already exist

Tags: mysql, database

Let's say I've a table `MYTABLE` having two columns

`SERIALNUMBER, USERNAME` (Where `SERIALNUMBER` is UNIQUE)

Multiple connections may attempt to update `USERNAME` with same `SERIALNUMBER` (Let's say 1).

So I am issuing query:

`SELECT USERNAME FROM MYTABLE WHERE SERIALNUMBER = 1 FOR UPDATE`

If this query return row (means record already exists) I am issuing update

`UPDATE MYTABLE SET USERNAME= <different name by each connection> WHERE SERIALNUMBER = 1`

Else (record doesn't already exist) I issue insert

`INSERT INTO MYTABLE (SERIALNUMBER, USERNAME) VALUES ( 1, <different name by each connection>)`

Finally I issue

`COMMIT`

**Expected behaviour:**

Connections holding same `SERIALNUMBER` in their query should wait at `SELECT.. FOR UPDATE` statement.

1. If record already exist, each connection should update it one by one with `SERIALNUMBER` it holds
2. If record doesn't exist, first connection granted lock for `SERIALNUMBER` it holds (since `SERIALNUMBER` doesn't already exist it's gap lock if am not wrong) should `INSERT` new record and consequent connections as they get access to the lock should find record already exist. So they should `UPDATE` the existing record.

**Actual behaviour:**

1. If record already exists, it works as expected and each connection update record with its `USERNAME`
2. if record doesn't already exists, all connections concurrently goes on trying to `INSERT` new record. Out of which, one succeeds and remaining gives exception. The exception is different for different isolation levels.

For `REPEATABLE READ` (which is default for InnoDB) it is:

> MySQL error code: 1213, SQLState: 40001,  #ERR: Deadlock found when
>   trying to get lock; try restarting transaction

For `READ COMMITTED` it is:

> MySQL error code: 1062, SQLState: 23000,  #ERR: Duplicate entry '1'
>   for key 'SERIALNUMBER'

**Problem Statement:**

I like to know how can I prevent connections concurrently trying to create new record for same field value (At the same time I want to allow concurrent record creations as long as field values are different)

Comment: You're doing this wrong. You should use INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ... That way the operation is entirely atomic, even if you aren't using transactions.